# XSLT transform of singleton/milestone elements

Tags: xslt

I'm looking for an elegant XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution to the following transform problem. I've simplified the markup below so "a" is the start milestone element, and "b" is the end milestone element. Everything between the "a" and the "b" must be wrapped with element "c".

Input:

```
<doc>
<line>Text text <a/>text<b/></line>
<line>Text <a/>text text</line>
<line>Text<b/> text <a/>text</line>
<line>Text text text</line>
<line>Text text<b/> text</line>
</doc>
```

Output:

```
<doc>
<line>Text text <c>text</c></line>
<line>Text <c>text text</c></line>
<line><c>Text</c> text <c>text</c></line>
<line><c>Text text text</c></line>
<line><c>Text text</c> text</line>
</doc>
```

In the real-world case, there are at least 5 variations each of the a/b/c elements to cater for. There are also tens of thousands of lines, many of which do not contain a/b or their variations. The real-world case also has a "sec" element wrapping groups of lines, where the a/b behaviour still needs to work through.

Our initial solution involved the use of preceding::* but this obviously brings significant performance issues for large XML documents, so is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: You might be able to solve the performance problem simply by using preceding-sibling rather than preceding. Unless the lines contain a rather larger number of nodes than those shown, preceding-sibling and following-sibling should not be excessively expensive.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay. We are currently using preceding-sibling but it still doesn't scale because we need to look back through the entire document to correctly determine the current line state. I'm guessing we'll have to switch to a SAX processing approach to solve this using a simple set of state flags.

Comment: OK, I guess I hadn't appreciated the semantics of your milestone tags. That suggests you need to move forward through the lines, maintaining state either by using recursion or in XSLT 3.0 using xsl:iterate.

Comment: I hadn't considered xsl:iterate, that may actually work for us if we can use an XSLT 3.0 transformation engine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michaely Kay for the inspiration. Forgetting for a moment about the mechanics of wrapping the <c>..</c> elements, the correct algorithm as implemented in XSLT 3.0 appears to be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/doc" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:iterate select="line">
            <xsl:param name="state">b</xsl:param>
            <xsl:variable name="lastState" select="local-name((a|b)[last()])"/>
            <xsl:variable name="nextState">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$lastState">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$lastState"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$state"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:if test="$state = 'a'"><startC/></xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:if test="$nextState = 'a'"><endC/></xsl:if>                    
            </xsl:copy>

            <xsl:next-iteration>
                <xsl:with-param name="state" select="$nextState"/>
            </xsl:next-iteration>                                        
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <startC/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <endC/>
</xsl:template>
```

Giving output:

```
<doc>
    <line>Text text <startC/>text<endC/></line>
    <line>Text <startC/>text text<endC/></line>
    <line><startC/>Text<endC/> text <startC/>text<endC/></line>
    <line><startC/>Text text text<endC/></line>
    <line><startC/>Text text<endC/> text</line>
</doc>
```